# Serialize to xml and namespace placement

Tags: c#, xml

I have a webpage with a button. On click, I pass my variables to a class to create an xml file. I am trying to add my namespaces right under the element called Message. It is not working properly.

Here is my class:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.1.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]


public partial class Request
    {

    private string sNameField;



    /// <remarks/>
    public string SName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sNameField = value;
        }
    }



    /// <remarks/>
    public Message Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = false)]

public partial class Message
{

    private AddO addOField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://pd.com")]
    public AddO AddO
    {
        get
        {
            return this.addOField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.addOField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://pd.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://pd.com", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class AddO
{

    private CaseD caseD;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.a.com")]
    public CaseD CaseD
    {
        get
        {
            return this.caseDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.caseDField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.a.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.a.com", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class CaseD
{

    private CaseA caseAField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.z.com")]
    public CaseA CaseA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.caseAField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.caseAField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.z.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.z.com", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class CaseA
{

    private Doc docField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.a.com")]
    public DocuE DocE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.docEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.docEField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Button Event:

```
caseA caseA = new caseA();



            caseD caseD = new caseD();
            caseD.caseA = caseA;



            addO addO = new addO();
            addO.caseD = caseD;



            Message Message = new Message();
            Message.addO = addO;

            Request  Request = new  Request();
            Request.Message = Message;

            Request.SName = "Hi";


            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("z", "http://www.z.com");
            ns.Add("pd", "http://pd.com");
            ns.Add("a", "http://www.a.com");

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request), new Type[] {typeof(Message), typeof(addO), typeof(caseD), typeof(caseA)});
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/images/test.xml"));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, Request, ns);
```

I get this in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request xmlns:a="http://www.a.com">
  <SName>hi</SName>

  <Message>
    <addO xmlns="http://pd.com">
      <a:caseD>
        <caseA xmlns="http://www.z.com">

        </caseA>
      </a:caseD>
    </addO>
  </Message>
</Request>
```

I need the namespaces to be only under the Message element:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request>

<SName>Hi</SName>

    <Message>
        <pd:addO
xmlns:a="http://www.a.com" 
xmlns:z="http://www.z.com" 
xmlns:pd="http://pd.com">
            <a:caseD>
                <z:caseA>

                </z:caseA>
            </a:caseD>
        </pd:addO>
    </Message>
</Request>
```

Comment: You likely need to use `XmlWriter` to carefully write out XML the way you like. Note that since both versions are identical from XML point of view there is not much in .Net to hint where to move prefix declarations.

Comment: Your test case doesn't compile -- the types `Doc` and `DocuE` are missing, as is the field `Request.messageField`.  Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter whether the root element or the child element has the namespace definitions -- your two XML samples are semantically identical.

Nevertheless, if you are dealing with a receiving system that does not handle this properly, you can take advantage of the [`[XmlAnyElementAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to do *nested serializations* with `XmlSerializer`, embedding the results of the inner serialization of the `AddO` element (including the required namespaces) inside the outer serialization of `Request`.

First you will need some extension methods to serialize from and to the `XElement` class, and other related utilities:

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static XmlSerializerNamespaces NoStandardXmlNamespaces()
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
        return ns;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            object result = (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return obj.SerializeToXElement(null, NoStandardXmlNamespaces());
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        return obj.SerializeToXElement(null, ns);
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        var element = doc.Root;
        if (element != null)
            element.Remove();
        return element;
    }

    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        serializer = serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        T returnValue = default(T);
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            object result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
            {
                returnValue = (T)result;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns, bool? standalone)
    {
        return GetXml(obj, null, ns, standalone);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns, bool? standalone)
    {
        serializer = serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (var textWriter = new Utf8StringWriter())
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " }; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                if (standalone != null)
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(standalone.Value);
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string RootXmlElementName(this Type type)
    {
        var xmlRoot = type.GetCustomAttribute<XmlRootAttribute>();
        if (xmlRoot != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlRoot.ElementName))
            return xmlRoot.ElementName;
        return type.Name;
    }
}

public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Next, define your classes including the `Message` class as follows.  Note that the classes in your question do not compile (some missing types) so I have simplified them:

```
public class Request
{
    public string SName { get; set; }

    public Message Message { get; set; }
}

public static class Namespaces
{
    public const string pd = "http://pd.com";
    public const string a = "http://www.a.com";
    public const string z = "http://www.z.com";

    public static XmlSerializerNamespaces GetNamespaces()
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("pd", pd);
        ns.Add("a", a);
        ns.Add("z", z);
        return ns;
    }
}

public class Message
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public AddO AddO { get; set; }

    // Do nested serialization here
    [XmlAnyElement]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XElement[] AddOXml
    {
        get
        {
            if (AddO == null)
                return null;
            var ns = Namespaces.GetNamespaces();
            var element = AddO.SerializeToXElement(ns);
            element.Name = element.Name.Namespace + "addO";
            return new[] { element };
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
                AddO = null;
            AddO = value.Select(x => { x.Name = x.Name.Namespace + typeof(AddO).RootXmlElementName(); return x.Deserialize<AddO>(); }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = Namespaces.pd)]
public class AddO
{
    [XmlElement("caseD", Namespace = Namespaces.a )]
    public CaseD CaseD { get; set; }
}

public class CaseD
{
    [XmlElement("caseA", Namespace = Namespaces.z)]
    public CaseA CaseA { get; set; }
}

public class CaseA
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, to test:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var request = new Request
        {
            SName = "Hi",
            Message = new Message
            {
                AddO = new AddO
                {
                    CaseD = new CaseD { CaseA = new CaseA { Value = "Test Value" } },
                }
            }
        };
        var xml = request.GetXml(XmlExtensions.NoStandardXmlNamespaces(), true);
        Debug.WriteLine(xml);
        var request2 = xml.LoadFromXML<Request>();
        Debug.WriteLine(request2.GetXml(XmlExtensions.NoStandardXmlNamespaces(), true));

        Debug.Assert(request.Message.AddO.CaseD.CaseA.Value == request2.Message.AddO.CaseD.CaseA.Value); // No assert.
    }
}
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IDu2dR).  XML output is:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
> <Request>
>     <SName>Hi</SName>
>     <Message>
>         <pd:addO xmlns:z="http://www.z.com" xmlns:a="http://www.a.com" xmlns:pd="http://pd.com">
>             <a:caseD>
>                 <z:caseA>
>                     <z:Value>Test Value</z:Value>
>                 </z:caseA>
>             </a:caseD>
>         </pd:addO>
>     </Message>
> </Request>
> ```